# TikZ: connect two unaligned nodes with a U-shaped line

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to connect two nodes with that are not aligned either in X or Y dimension, node 2 is to the lower right of node 1 (for the sake of the argument). The line should start from node 1, goes to the right horizontally until it's above node 2, then I want it to make a U turn and connect to node 2 from the right.

The following code produces kind of what I want:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts,amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{scopes}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}


\tikzset{copy/.style={circle,inner sep=0pt,fill=black,minimum
    size=5pt} }

\def\tnboxsize{6mm}

\tikzset{box/.style={rectangle,draw=black,fill=none, minimum
    width=\tnboxsize, minimum height=\tnboxsize,
    shape border uses incircle}}

\tikzset{blank/.style={rectangle,inner
    sep=0pt,draw=none,fill=none,minimum size=0pt} }

\tikzset{blankbig/.style={rectangle,inner sep=0pt,draw=none,fill=none,minimum
    size=\tnboxsize} }


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
      \node[blank] (out1) {};
      \node[blank] (out2) [below=0.5 of out1] {};
      \node[blank] (out3) [below=0.5 of out2] {};

      \node[blank] (anchorout) at ($(out1)!0.5!(out2)$) {};
      \node[copy] (copy) [right=0.6 of anchorout] {};
      \node[box] (c) [right=of out3] {$C$};

      \draw [-] (out1) -- (copy);
      \draw [-] (out2) -- (copy);
      \draw [-] (out3) -- (c);
      \draw [-] (copy) -- +(0.75,0) .. controls +(0.7,0) and +(0.7,0) .. (c);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Like this:

[image: Good]

However, to do this, I had to manually adjust the numbers for the controlling points in
`\draw [-] (copy) -- +(0.75,0) .. controls +(0.7,0) and +(0.7,0) .. (c)`.

For example, when these numbers are messed up, the picture looks like this:

[image]

Is there a way to enforce the behavior like in the first picture without manually adjusting the positions of the control points?

Comment: Did `rounded corners` and `-|` solve your problem?
For example: `\draw[rounded corners=8] (copy) -| ($(c)+(.7,0)$) -- (c);` (You might want to try other value for the rounded corners)

Comment: In case of a curve my proposal is somethimg like: `\draw [-] (copy) to[in=90,out=0] ([shift={(1,0)}]$(c)!0.5!(copy)$) to[in=0,out=270](c);` but @Vinzza's suggestion is probably easier

Comment: @Vinzza it seems like a good option, actually! I was thinking of something similar but didn't know how to use this `($(c)+(.7,0)$)` notation properly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

some how similar to propositions in above comments, however also address some off-topic issues:

```
\documentclass[12pt, tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts,amsmath}

\usetikzlibrary{calc,
                decorations.pathreplacing,
                positioning,
                shapes.geometric, scopes}
\tikzset{
 copy/.style = {circle,inner sep=0pt,fill=black,minimum size=5pt},
  box/.style = {rectangle,draw=black,fill=none, 
                minimum width=\tnboxsize, minimum height=\tnboxsize,
                shape border uses incircle},
blank/.style = {rectangle,inner sep=0pt, draw=none,fill=none, minimum size=0pt}, % <--- not needed, rather use coordinate 
blankbig/.style = {rectangle,inner sep=0pt,draw=none,fill=none, minimum size=\tnboxsize} 
        }
\def\tnboxsize{6mm}


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[thick,
    node distance = 5mm and 6mm  % <--- added
                        ]
    \coordinate                 (out1);
    \coordinate[below=of out1]  (out2);
    \coordinate[below=of out2]  (out3);

    \node[copy] (copy)  [right=of $(out1)!0.5!(out2)$]  {}; % <--- removed one coordinate
    \node[box]  (c)     [right=of out3 -| copy]         {$C$};

    \draw   (out1) -- (copy)  % <--- slightly shorter code
            (out2) -- (copy) 
            (out3) -- (c) 
            (copy.east) -- (copy -| c.east) % <--- auxiliary coordinate 

                        .. controls +(0.5,0) and +(0.5,0) .. (c.east);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can do the following (just changing tour last `\draw` command):

1. draw from `copy` to the point that has `copy` y-coord and the east point of `c` as x-coord:

   ```
   (copy) -- (copy -| c.east)
   ```
2. and then go to `c.east` using a curve starting with angle 0, arriving at angle 0, and looseness 2 (that should be half a circle, more or less):

   ```
   to [out=0, in=0, looseness=2]
   ```

Like that:

```
 \draw (copy) -- (copy -| c.east) 
      to[out=0, in=0, looseness=2] (c.east);
```

You get:

[image]

Full MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts,amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{scopes}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}


\tikzset{copy/.style={circle,inner sep=0pt,fill=black,minimum
    size=5pt} }

\def\tnboxsize{6mm}

\tikzset{box/.style={rectangle,draw=black,fill=none, minimum
    width=\tnboxsize, minimum height=\tnboxsize,
    shape border uses incircle}}

\tikzset{blank/.style={rectangle,inner
    sep=0pt,draw=none,fill=none,minimum size=0pt} }

\tikzset{blankbig/.style={rectangle,inner sep=0pt,draw=none,fill=none,minimum
    size=\tnboxsize} }


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
      \node[blank] (out1) {};
      \node[blank] (out2) [below=0.5 of out1] {};
      \node[blank] (out3) [below=0.5 of out2] {};

      \node[blank] (anchorout) at ($(out1)!0.5!(out2)$) {};
      \node[copy] (copy) [right=0.6 of anchorout] {};
      \node[box] (c) [right=of out3] {$C$};

      \draw [-] (out1) -- (copy);
      \draw [-] (out2) -- (copy);
      \draw [-] (out3) -- (c);
      %
      \draw (copy) -- (copy -| c.east)
          to[out=0, in=0, looseness=2] (c.east);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```